# Read first token from output

Tags: bash, shell

I have this command:

```
num_lines="$(wc -l "$HOME/my_bash_history")"
```

Which yields:

```
17 /Users/alex/my_bash_history
```

So I tried to get the first token using:

```
local read num_lines < <(wc -l "$HOME/my_bash_history")
```

But all I get is empty result:

> num lines:

Anybody know why?

Comment: Or, in addition to John's answer, after `num_lines="$(wc -l "$HOME/my_bash_history")"`, simply use a *parameter expansion*, `num_lines="${num_lines%% *}"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`wc` reports the file name **unless** it is reading from stdin.  So, keep it simple, just use:

```
$ num_lines="$(wc -l <"$HOME/my_bash_history")"
$ echo "$num_lines"
17
```

If you really want to use `read` with *process substitution*, then use two arguments to `read` like this:

```
$ read num_lines fname < <(wc -l "$HOME/my_bash_history")
$ echo "$num_lines"
17
```

or, use a *here-string* like this:

```
$ read num_lines fname <<<"$(wc -l "$HOME/my_bash_history")"
$ echo "$num_lines"
17
```

When `read` reads a line, the shell first splits the lines into words.  The words are assigned to each argument in turn with the last argument receiving whatever remains.  In our case, this means the the number is assigned to `num_lines` and whatever words follow the number are assigned to `fname`.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
num_lines="$(wc -l $HOME/my_bash_history)"
echo "${num_lines%% *}"
```

**explanation**

```
${num_lines%% *}  # delete all after first blank
```

Comment: Well, at least that is an improvement. If you explain you are using a *parameter expansion*, the OP can at least look it up in `man bash` to gain a deeper understanding of how it can be used.